# How to prevent ajax call from extending session timeout?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, session-timeout

I have in my web application (asp.net) auto-refresh function that goes to the server and updates the displayed data.
Every call (as I read and tested), reset the session timeout and therefore it never ends.

Is there any way to prevent from a specific call to extend the timeout?

Is there any way to check in the background from client-side if the user is still authenticated and if not to redirect him to login page?

I check in every ajax start, and if I get 403 error I redirect him. Can I do it without a real operation from the user?

Comment: Can we see some code and HTML?

Comment: Auto Refresh is build from a few ajax calls that gets data from the server (folder list, document list both are sync) and load templates from the server using $get.

Comment: Is it MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: ASP.NET web app (edited)

Comment: Does your query to DB takes so long? then its a problem. I think one solution could be create a separate service asmx or WCF and use that to fetch the data, hopefully that will not reset the session timeouts.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I want the user to be redirected to the login page after session timeout. The problem is that I have a background ajax call that refreshes the page. This ajax call reset the session timeout and although the user didn't touch the UI for long, the session is not expired.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will work or not, but still you can give one try.

I found it on other thread of stack overflow. The idea is it removes the session auth cookie from response, that way it is not refreshed.

```
// Hide the cookie so this call doesn't extend the user's ticket
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
ctx.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
```

[How do I stop ASP.net forms authentication / session from renewing in setInterval ajax web service call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102563/how-do-i-stop-asp-net-forms-authentication-session-from-renewing-in-setinterva)

Comment: Any idea how to not extend session for polling ajax requests when using  OWIN authentication